# Does passing struct into a function also using copy-on-write for optimisation, or actual copy does happen immediately?

Tags: swift

Based on https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ClassesAndStructures.html

> Collections defined by the standard library like arrays, dictionaries,
>   and strings use an optimization to reduce the performance cost of
>   copying. Instead of making a copy immediately, these collections share
>   the memory where the elements are stored between the original instance
>   and any copies. If one of the copies of the collection is modified,
>   the elements are copied just before the modification. The behavior you
>   see in your code is always as if a copy took place immediately.

I was wondering, how about passing struct as function parameter, as in the following code?

```
noteStruct = NoteStruct()
// Does actual copy happen immediately?
someFunctionWhichPerformsReadOnly(note)

func someFunctionWhichPerformsReadOnly( _ noteStruct: NoteStruct)
```

Does actual copy happen immediately, when passing struct as function parameter, or Swift compiler is smart enough to avoid actual copy in the above case?

---

### Example

```
struct  Note {
    var data = "original"

    mutating func mutate() {
        data = "modified"
    }

    func readonly() {
        print("read : \(data)")
    }
}

func doSomething1(_ note: Note) {
    var localNote = note
    localNote.mutate()
}

func doSomething2(_ note: Note) {
    note.readonly()
}

let note = Note()
doSomething1(note)
doSomething2(note)
```

Will Swift smart enough, to avoid actual copy, when calling `doSomething1` and `doSomething2`?

Comment: No. This is not duplicated, as the provided reference answer doesn't discuss about function parameter without `inout`

Comment: Passing function parameter without `inout` is treated as a read-only `let` constant. Since it is read-only, copy is not necessary until you assign it to a `var` and modify it.  You can use `array.withUnsafeBytes { (ptr) -> Void in print(ptr)}` to check the actual memory address and experiment your self (`Array` is a `struct`).

Comment: It is a duplicate question. The other question specifically asks about passing an Array, for example, to a function. Same as this question.